# How do I know Mathematica is doing exact algebra?

Tags: equation-solving

I am looking for zeroes of the following polynomial:

`-36 - 20 a1 a2 + 16 a2 b1 + a2^2 b1^2 + 16 a1 b2 - 20 b1 b2 -  2 a1 a2 b1 b2 + a1^2 b2^2`

in the region

`a1*a2 <= -5 && b1*b2 <= -5`

Simple enough of a command

`Solve[8 + a2 b1 + a1 b2 + 2 Sqrt[-5 - a1 a2] Sqrt[-5 - b1 b2] == 0 &&  a1*a2 <= -5 && b1*b2 <= -5, {a1, a2, b1, b2}]`
Tells me that there is no solution.

How do I know that Mathematica is doing exact algebra (like using quadratic formula for a quadratic equation) rather than some numerical estimation? In the Solve documentation I find

"When expr involves only polynomial equations and inequalities over real or complex domains, then Solve can always in principle solve directly for vars."

I am just wondering if I can use Mathematica as "proof" that no zeroes exist in that region.

I am sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: Use `Reduce`. "The result of Reduce[expr, vars] always describes exactly the same mathematical set as expr."

Comment: Off-topic, but one could rewrite the expression as `-100 - 4 a1 a2 b1 b2 + (8 + a2 b1 + a1 b2)^2 - 20 (a1 a2 + b1 b2)` and from there the inequalities guarantee positivity (the first tow terms sum to at least zero, next is a square hence nonnegative, last is at least 200).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to solve the problem in a different way. E.g. by defining regions and check if there is an empty intersection:

```
r1 = ImplicitRegion[-36 - 20 a1 a2 + 16 a2 b1 + a2^2 b1^2 + 
    16 a1 b2 - 20 b1 b2 - 2 a1 a2 b1 b2 + a1^2 b2^2 == 0, {a1, a2, b1,
    b2}];
r2 = ImplicitRegion[a1*a2 <= -5 && b1*b2 <= -5, {a1, a2, b1, b2}];

RegionIntersection[r1, r2];
(* EmptyRegion[4] *)
```

Of course, you could still argue that we do not know how MMA calculate the regions and that MMA may make the same error twice.

Comment: `r2` is not defined..

Comment: Sorry copy and past error. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

`Reduce` or `Method->Reduce` in `Solve` are powerful then only use `Solve`.

```
Reduce[{8 + a2 b1 + a1 b2 + 2 Sqrt[-5 - a1 a2] Sqrt[-5 - b1 b2] == 0, 
  a1*a2 <= -5, b1*b2 <= -5}, {a1, a2, b1, b2}]
```

> `False`

- Change  `b1*b2<=-5` to  `b1+b2<=-5`

```
Reduce[{8 + a2 b1 + a1 b2 + 2 Sqrt[-5 - a1 a2] Sqrt[-5 - b1 b2] == 0, 
  a1*a2 <= -5, b1 + b2 <= -5}, {a1, a2, b1, b2}]
```

> `a1 ∈ Reals && a1 != 0 && a2 == -(5/a1) &&  b1 <= (8 - 5 a1)/(a1 - a2) && b2 == (-8 - a2 b1)/a1`

Comment: Did you mean to say Reduce is more powerful than Solve?

Comment: @2132123 Yes, and `Reduce` return `False` means that the there no solution in such equations.